# How to add an existing maven project to another maven project as a module?

Tags: maven, module, pom.xml

I have a maven project which needs to be a module for another maven project. Is there a way to achieve this in eclipse or from the cli?
I added the

```
 <module>existing_maven_proj</module>
```

in the POM of the parent project and ran maven install but this doesn't seem to add the module

Comment: Such a `module` declaration will tell Maven to look for a project under the sub-folder `existing_maven_proj`, and Maven will expect to find a pom there. Does that sub-folder exists?

Comment: thanks for the pointer, there does not. Do I create a subfolder ad name it as the name of the module?

Comment: Yes you need to move the current project and make it a sub-folder of where the pom you are invoking Maven on is.

Comment: thanks! Thats useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update the internal Eclipse configuration for the updated maven project structure. Run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

in you maven top level module. You might also need to import the new maven module. Just do a regular "Import existing maven project into workspace" to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

If you use M2e with Eclipse you do not need to do that, because Eclipse resolves dependencies across the workspace. You just need to have the two projects open and your dependencies declared correctly.